# Any use of #if inside my #each loop in my Handlebars template causes the browser page to crash

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This is pretty basic, but I've spent hours trying to figure out why I can't seem to use Handlebars's built-in #if helper inside the #each loop of my template. The second I insert a reference to {{#if}}, Chrome (or Safari) crash and the console reports:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
meta
targetSetFor 
sendEvent
Ember.Evented.Ember.Mixin.create.trigger
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.trigger
newFunc
(anonymous function)
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.invokeRecursively
newFunc
```

(repeats many times)

Why is this causing me a recursion fault in Ember?

```
<div id="gridChannelListDiv" tabindex="0">
{{#each item in content}}
    {{#if item.hilight}}
        <div class="gridCellHilight">
            ...
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class="gridCell">
            ...
        </div>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

This happens even if the {{#if}} statement does nothing.

```
<div id="gridChannelListDiv" tabindex="0">
{{#each item in content}}
    {{#if}}{{/if}}   // this line will cause instant "oh snap" crash

    <div class="gridCell">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

The associated ArrayController contains a simple list of 5 Ember objects in "content" and the templates work fine until I insert an #if. 
Baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your code. Could be a bug in your version of ember or perhaps an incompatible version of a supporting library (handlebars/jQuery). Either that or something crazy going on in some other aspect of your application.

I created a simple app/controller and used it to get your template code up and running here: http://jsbin.com/ekemak/2/edit - Tried in both chrome and safari, in both cases app works with no js errors.

```
//app.js
App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('content', [
      Em.Object.create({name: 'aaa', hilight: false}),
      Em.Object.create({name: 'BBB', hilight: true}),
      Em.Object.create({name: 'ccc', hilight: false})
    ]);
  }
});


//index.hbs
<ul>
{{#each item in content}}
  {{#if item.hilight}}
    <div class="gridCellHilight">
        <B>{{item.name}}</B>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="gridCell">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}   
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps narrow things down for me. I will continue to investigate... there's a chance your initial speculation is correct - the team I joined is using some libraries that are a couple of versions back - maybe they're just broken. Thanks.

Comment: There's a bit of speculation here as we didn't conclusively determine what was going on, but it appears this might have been caused by having dynamically loaded and compiled template files and also having a stale hard-coded reference to the template in our View. Somehow, I think this set up a recursive loop in some cases, but why #if would trigger it, is not clear, but after removing the hard-coded reference to the template, things appear to be behaving as expected.